# Laravel generates Blank Page after login in Web Hosting Server, but in Local Server it works fine

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have an application that works normally on my Local Server. Then, I've transferred these files to my web hosting server to a subdomain. `https://subdomain.abc.com`

The files are transferred as below.

Local drive Folder/Files in Public Folder -> subdomain.abc.com

Local drive other Folder/Files -> subdomain.abc.com/v1.0

Then the autoloader has been updated in index.php file.

```
require __DIR__.'/../subdomain.abc.com/v1.0/vendor/autoload.php';
```

also,

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../subdomain.abc.com/v1.0/bootstrap/app.php';
```

When I launch the application on the server (say `https://subdomain.abc.com`), it redirects to the login page. After logged-in, it is supposed to redirect to the dashboard route. But, instead of redirecting to another route, I've received a blank page with the same URL in the address bar (`https://subdomain.abc.com`).

Even, there is no error recorded.

When tried manually to access `https://subdomain.abc.com/dashboard`, received `403 | Forbidden Page`.

Based on the answers in similar posts, tried to update `.htaccess` file, but had no luck at all.

Server PHP Version: 8.0

What would be the problem here?

Comment: Try `php artisan optimize:clear` just in case

Comment: Can you post your dashboard redirection code? Which file/controller is it located in?

Comment: Its showing blank because in production `APP_DEBUG` is typically set to `FALSE` depending how your logs are set up you should still see the error in `storage/logs/`

Comment: My server provider doesn't allow to use SSH. So, not able to run artisan commands. Or, guide me if there is another way to run this command @gowl

Comment: @Second2None, I've set`APP_DEBUG` to `TRUE`. But, still there is no error in log file

Comment: If you can't connect via SSH you can set up some endpoints in your app that run artisan commands.  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#closure-commands

Comment: @fufubrocat,
`class LoginController extends Controller
{
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
public function __construct(){$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');}
}`

RouteServiceProvider:
`public const HOME = '/';`

Comment: @fufubrocat,

web.php:
`Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
if( !$request->user() == null ) {
if ( $request->user()->roles()->where('role', '=', 'Admin')->exists() ) {
return redirect('/dashboard');
} elseif ( $request->user()->roles()->where('role', '=', 'User')->exists() ) {
return redirect('/job_booking');
}
} else {
return redirect('/login');
}
});`

Comment: @Second2None, @gowl, as I'm using Bootstrap Larval ui for authentication, I've just updated `Artisan::call('optimize:clear')` command in `subdomain.abc.com/v1.0/vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/RedirectsUsers.php` file.
The code:
`trait RedirectsUsers { public function redirectPath() { if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) { Artisan::call('optimize:clear'); return $this->redirectTo(); } return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/'; } }`.
But still receiving the same blank page. Am I in the right way?

Comment: @Nimal `"But, instead of redirecting to another route, I've received a blank page with the same URL in the address bar (https://subdomain.abc.com)."` — It seems to me like this is the result of your `else { return redirect('/login'); }` condition. Can you check whether `Auth::check()` returns true upon login?

Comment: @fufubrocat, you are right!

It's my mistake to not form proper if-else logic, to catch when the user doesn't have any role.
Thanks for your support!